# How to show that a given mixed two-qubit state is separable?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

A pure state is separable (unentangled) if it can be written as a tensor product of states of each qubit.

A mixed state is separable, if it can be written as a probability distribution over separable pure states.

Consider the mixed state which is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$ with the probability of $\frac{1}{2}$, and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle+|10\rangle)$ with the probability of $\frac{1}{2}$.

How to show that this mixed state is separable?

Comment: For the two qubit mixed state that you have given, this may be of interest to you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peres%E2%80%93Horodecki_criterion. Essentially, if the approach described there is taken, and negative eigenvalues are obtained, then it is not separable.

Answer (score 4):

Begin by writing down the density matrix

$$
\begin{align}
\rho_{AB} &= \frac{1}{4}\left[(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)(\langle00|+\langle11|)\right] + \frac{1}{4}\left[(|01\rangle+|10\rangle)(\langle01|+\langle0|)\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
$$

At this stage we already see that $\rho_{AB}$ satisfies the [Peres–Horodecki criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peres%E2%80%93Horodecki_criterion): if we transpose all four $2\times 2$ blocks then we obtain

$$
(I \otimes T)\rho_{AB} = \frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^T & \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^T \\
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^T & \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^T \\
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} = \rho_{AB}
$$

which is a state. In case of two qubit (and qubit-qutrit) pairs the criterion is both necessary and sufficient, so $\rho_{AB}$ is separable.

Note that for larger systems, the criterion is necessary, but not sufficient.

---

In this case, it is also not too difficult to see how $\rho_{AB}$ may be expressed as a convex combination of product states

$$
\begin{align}
\rho_{AB} &= \frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \frac{1}{8}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} + \frac{1}{8}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(|+\rangle\langle+| \otimes |+\rangle\langle+| \,+\, |-\rangle\langle-| \otimes |-\rangle\langle-|\right).
\end{align}
$$